# Fill dropdown with a single table MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, combobox

I am trying to develop a dropdown in cascadig, which suggests to the user the characteristics of a piece of furniture stored in a table called Vanity Furniture (model, type of sheet and measurements).

[image: ScreenShoot]

but when you get to the combobox of the measurements this suggests the measurements of all types of sheets selected in the previous combo and not the measures according to the model and according to the type of sheet

[image: DataBase]

To fill the second combobox from the first one I call the GetLamina method and to fill the last one I call the GetMedidas method

My Controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetLamina(int ModeloMueble)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var modelo = db.MuebleVanitorios.Where(m => m.Kn_CodigoModeloMueble == ModeloMueble);
            return Json(modelo);
        }

        public JsonResult GetMedidas(int LaminaDecorativa)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var lamina = db.MuebleVanitorios.Where(m => m.Kn_CodigoLaminaDecorativa == LaminaDecorativa);
            return Json(lamina);
        }
```

My View:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoModeloMueble, "Modelo Modulo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Kn_CodigoModeloMueble", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoModeloMueble, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoLaminaDecorativa, "Lamina Decorativa", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Kn_CodigoLaminaDecorativa", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoLaminaDecorativa, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio, "Medidas Mueble", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.DropDownList("Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio", null, ((IList<System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata>)ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)[0].Watermark, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @required = "true" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Kn_CodigoModeloMueble").change(function () {
                $("#Kn_CodigoLaminaDecorativa").empty();
                $("#Kn_CodigoLaminaDecorativa").append('<option value="0">[Seleccione Lamina...]</option>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetLamina")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { ModeloMueble: $("#Kn_CodigoModeloMueble").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                            $("#Kn_CodigoLaminaDecorativa").append('<option value="'
                             + data.Kn_CodigoLaminaDecorativa + '">'
                             + data.v_Nombre + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Error inesperado.' + ex);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Kn_CodigoLaminaDecorativa").change(function () {
                $("#Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio").empty();
                $("#Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio").append('<option value="0">[Seleccione Medidas...]</option>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetMedidas")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { LaminaDecorativa: $("#Kn_CodigoLaminaDecorativa").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                            $("#Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio").append('<option value="'
                             + data.Kn_CodigoMuebleVanitorio + '">'
                             + data.Medidas + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Error inesperado.' + ex);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        });
</script>
```

Then in my view with Javascript and a bit of ajax, I change the state of the dropdowns, what am I doing wrong? What am I missing? any help for me? recommendations?

Comment: Your image looks like it's working correctly. You're wanting to *only* see the measurements for the filtered options, correct? So, if I choose Madera then I should only see the two measurements from your table; right?

Comment: The measurements must be displayed according to the Model and According to the type of the sheet, in the case of the example ... the model would be MODEL ELE 3 (Kn_CodeModelModeble = 3) and the type of sheet would be WOOD (Kn_CodigoLaminaDecorativa = 2), given these Parameters should show in measures 60X40X20, I explain myself well? @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: Yes, thank you. It sounds like your controller needs a method that accepts two ids (2 and 3 in your example). Then it would be an `&&` condition in the `Where` lambda.

Comment: For that you would have to have 1 single method? Would I have to alter my javascript code? @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: This is not really making sense. If you only wanted to display one item, then why is it a dropdownlist. And the purpose of dropdownlists if to display data from relational tables, and you not accessing data from relationship tables

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it's a dynamic dropdown; there are cases in which many are possible I presume.

Comment: Well, yes; one method because you're basically filtering by two columns. You could filter by one on the back and then another on the front but why? Yes, you'd also have to change your JS as the ajax call would have to change; right?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, It makes no sense. OP has not even shown the table that stores the type of sheet, and the tables that store the sizes associated which each type of sheet. OP's table not even normalized

Comment: @StephenMuecke, fair enough. I think it makes sense in that I understand what they're trying to achieve. Are they doing a great job of presenting their problem here, probably not.